# gstat output on FreeBSD: does it show an average over time?

Tags: freebsd, io

When you run the gstat command on FreeBSD to get information about i/o performance, you can pass the -I (interval) option to change the default interval from 1 sec to some other time frame.

My question is, does gstat output average metrics over the interval period, or is the output just a snapshot of what going on at that moment?

Answer (score 2):

gstat show average across given interval for all metrics except `L(q)` (queue length).
`L(q)` is snapshot of that moment.

In gstat the devstat_compute_statistics() is used, and this function documented in [devstat(3)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=devstat&sektion=3).